# Floating of div does not work in Chrome while works in other browsers

Tags: html, css

There are four links in my HTML page.(left side of the page). I need to show and hide a related div for each link when I am clicking on a link.

If i clicked on first link then I need to show first div on right side of the page. Again if i clicked on second link then I need to show the second div after the first div.

To do this i have aligned all these divs in to left.(given a style as "float:left"). This is working properly in Firefox and IE. But does not work in Google Chrome. I can see all these divs in same position in chrome instead of one after one.

i really appreciate if any one can give a useful answer. THANK YOU

Comment: jsfiddle.net, show us your code

Comment: Please, upload your principal code on jsfiddle.net and give link.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you put all these four divs inside another div (container) and set width for that containing div the same as your four dives or just 2-3px bigger. Like this:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 202px">
    <div id="inner1" style="width: 200px; float: left"></div>
    <div id="inner2" style="width: 200px; float: left"></div>
    <div id="inner3" style="width: 200px; float: left"></div>
    <div id="inner4" style="width: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

If you use float positioning, you should always use a container div, which will tell your browser an exact space it has to position the inner divs. I was always told that using floats without containers can produce unpredictable results in any browser.